# Configuring Ubuntu for the first time on notebook, hungs up

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support, interface

New notebook with Ubuntu preinstalled, after first power on tried to configure system first time: after successfully connecting to network, next step for setting up keyboard layout: as laptop have ENG/RUS keyboard, I wanted add Russian keyboard layout: here is something not intuitive, and obviously wrong: there was selection for 8 or even 10 "versions"(!) of Russian language, which is completely wrong (for those who dont know Russian language - there is ONLY ONE Russian language, there is NOT exist such mythical "Russian(Tatar)", "Russian(Sakha)", "Russian (DOS)", etc - all these probably inspired by microsoft myphs), so I assume I choosed something wrong - I want return to step back, or start from beginning, but I only have empty Ubuntu screen with few settings on top right corner of screen, I can go into system settings , etc. I simply can no "Log out" or "Power off" notebook, as Ubuntu not responding on these commands, not hungs up, but **not react** on Log out or Power off. How to Power off or log out notebook properly, to start configure from beginning?

Comment: Try left Alt + SysRq + B, or pressing the power button for 5 seconds.

Comment: Alt + SysRq + B works (SysRq key is on PrtScr).

Comment: I think there are 8 or 10 options for Russian language *keyboard layouts* (not Russian languages). Throughout computing history, people have used a variety of different keyboard layouts -- English has many, many options to choose from as well.

Comment: Yes, _keyboard layout_ options,  correct. However, all these layouts versions for particular language are made m$oft not for convenience, but with the goal to increase sales and get more profit.